# how to determine what is causing my w3wp process re-starts

Tags: iis-7, logparser, w3wp.exe

Seem like something is causing my w3wp process every few minutes. There are no code changes or changes to web.config that can cause this. Application pool IdleTimeout is also set to 2 hours. I am just trying to find what is causing this process re-start. Does this type of information goes into any of IIS log. Currently I am looking at logs located at C:\Inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1 but don't find any indications about these re-starts. Any idea where can I find this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be an unhandled exception of some kind.

Have you checked the Windows Application Error Log?

Comment: yeah. There is nothing in the application logs. I was just wondering if application pool re-start or app domain re-starts get logged in any of IIS provided logs

Comment: No, not by default. You can, of course, add your own logging (to the Windows Application log or wherever) in the Application_Start or Application_End events in Global.asax.

Answer (score 0):

If you have .net application running:

Have a look in global web.config in the .net framework folder and activate the setting healthMonitoring.